# How to customize the CSS style of input depending the value of the id

Tags: html, css, angular, forms, css-selectors

I am looking for a solution to customize the CSS of the form fields (for example: input) based on the value of the id.

This is an example of my issue:

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field class="form-field-container" >
    <input tabindex="0" id="{{ myVar.name }}" matInput [formControlName]="myVar.name" autocomplete="off"
      [placeholder]="myVar.placeholder" />        
  </mat-form-field>
```

My standard CSS:

```
.mat-input-element {
    background: transparent !important;
    color: #000000 !important;
    border: none !important;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    
}
.input.mat-input-element {
    margin-top: 1% !important;
}
```

What I'm looking for is:

- if myVar.name = val1, then use `width: 30%;` in CSS
- if myVar.name = val2, then use `width: 20%;` in CSS

I've tried using selectors, but it just doesn't work:

```
input[id="val1"] {
   width: 30%;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show us a runnable snippet because at the moment I don’t see why the selector #val1 wouldn’t work.

Comment: Regarding your comments, could you post the compiled HTML? It seems that the id are not the one you're expecting. For instance, do they start with a number?

Comment: i have updated the post ,chack again please Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Both of the other answers does answer your question, if you choose to do it that way and you have the values in advance and can add them to the CSS. But if you don't have that, you can apply the ngClass selector to an input. Here is an example from the project I'm working on right now, which demonstrates use of a conditional to apply a class:

```
<input type="text"
   [ngClass]="ingredient.drugName == 'DRUG NAME NOT FOUND'
     ? 'text-danger fw-bold' //applying these two classes if the condition is met
     : '<some-other-class>'" //whatever class you want if the condition is false
```

Here is more info: https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Answer (score 0):

If you know the value of the variable you should use :

```
#val1 {
    /* your css code goes here */
}
```

Comment: No, this solution is not working, I've tried it already

Comment: Do you mind sharing your complete CSS code ? `#val1` is the way to do this, you may have something wrong elsewhere...

Comment: i have updated the post ,chack again please Thanks

Comment: Why do you have so many `!important` rules ? As i can see this takes priority over the #id selector. If you put the #id selector with the `!important` does it work better ? If it does you should take some time to clean this up, or you will have a hard time understanding what's going on with your CSS code

Answer (score 0):

you need to define some CSS for the various id types
eg:

if you need to set the width to 30% when the id of the element is "myId1"
you need to specify this in your .css file

```css
#myId1 {
    width: 30%;
}
```

so now when myVar will be "myId1" it will set the element's width to 30%

Answer (score 0):

Both `#val1` and `input[id="val1"]` are valid selectors that work.

The `width` is not applied because your CSS is not clean. **The specificity of your selector is not enough**, because you inverted the cascade by using [`!important`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/important).

If you inspect the applied styles in your browser’s developer tools, you will notice that the selector matches, but that the `width` property is not applied.

[image: A screenshot from developer tools showing the width property stroke through in the id selector]

Normally, class selectors `.class` and attribute selectors `[attr]` have the same specificity, so the one later in code will overwrite properties of the preceding one.

But by using `!important`, the cascade is inverted, and `width: 100%` keeps applied.

[See CSS Specicify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

```css
.mat-input-element {
…
   width: 100% !important; /* here is the reason, remove important! */
}

input[id="val1"] {
  width: 30%;
}
```

### Don’t put data logic inside CSS

It is generally not advised to style elements by means of their ID. Changing the ID based on some data value is particularly smelly.

I join Rich’s recommendation to [conditionally assign classes](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) based on the value. This way the data logic stays out of CSS, and the code becomes more readable.

```
<input type="text"
   [ngClass]="ingredient.drugName == 'DRUG NAME NOT FOUND'
     ? 'text-danger fw-bold' //applying these two classes if the condition is met
     : '<some-other-class>'" //whatever class you want if the condition is false
```

**Don’t forget to provide a label**, it’s very important for accessibility, and usability in general.

The context is unclear here, but an input needs a border and a focus indicator, which usually is an outline. Don’t forget please (: